# Is it ok to turn off and unplug my ups at night?

Tags: ups

Hello I have a line interactive UPS that my computer and tv are plugged into, at night I have this habit of turning off and unplugging ( from the wall outlet) all electric devices that I don't use. Is it ok? or does it shorten its life expectancy?

Comment: I agree with @FrankThomas . Computers (and other electronics) don’t die from old age, they die from power-on spikes.

Comment: @Aganju UPS batteries die from old age every three to five years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will shorten the life expectancy of its batteries.

Every night, with the UPS unplugged, the batteries self-discharge. Every day, when you plug the UPS back in, the batteries have to charge back up to compensate for the self-discharge. This daily partial discharge, full charge cycle will reduce the battery life. Typically, a UPSes batteries have to be replaced every three to five years. Daily shutdowns will likely reduce this life to more like two to three years.

In exchange for this reduction in battery life, you are probably prolonging the life of the non-replaceable parts of the UPS. However, these parts rarely fail.

You probably aren't even saving that much energy because you will see increased electricity consumption in the morning when you plug the UPS back in. A line-interactive UPS doesn't have much of its internal parts on when the input power is normal and the batteries are fully charged -- it's just keeping the batteries charged.

Comment: To be honest I don't do it to save power it's just for safety..

Comment: What is your concern?

Comment: I heard about some electronic devices catching fire that's why I turn them off when not in use  I don't want something like that to happen when I'm asleep that's all.

Comment: UPSs are designed to remain on all the time. But if you're really worried about it, you can prioritize your peace of mind over the life of the batteries.

Comment: UPSes generally improve the quality of the power and protect against faults that would cause electrical issues like you are worried about. So, unplugging and damaging the UPS is probably having the opposite impact you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend turning off the UPS power button but keeping it plugged in to maintain the charge. What I found is that when continuously running the battery will become weak and if power goes out it is not strong enough to keep my items running. This happens maybe about once a month or sometimes twice a month. Any amount of time is unacceptable. However I found if I turn the the power switch off it fully charges and loss of power never happens now.

Comment: The type of battery is important and a big reason UPS' typically have lead acid batteries is because these work well for the job of being plugged in all the time. Your advice seems more appropriate for older Lithium Ion batteries.